# Remove objects from NsMutableArray with removeObjectsInArray(someArray) in swift

Tags: swift, swift-array

I have two NSMutableArray's 
I am trying to remove the MutableArray from other Array with removeObjectsInArray() method 
Here is my code:

```
arrayImage.removeObjectsInArray(arrayDeleteImage)
```

But it requires a filter (NSPredicate), I don't understand why it's requried..
 I have implement the filter but it's giving me an error..

```
 arrayImage = arrayImage.filter //error:Nsmutable does not have member filter
    { value in
        !contains(arrayDeleteImage, value) //Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
    }
```

How can I remove the array objects from the other array ?

Comment: Has it fixed your problem?

Comment: No, but i am getting reference from your code and it's done. thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arrayOne:[NSMutableArray]
var arrayTwo:[NSMutableArray]

for ar in arrayTwo
{
         arrayOne.removeObject(ar)
}
```

Comment: `for deleteimge in arrayDeleteImage
        {
            println("\(deleteimge)")
            arrayImage.removeObjectAtIndex(Int(deleteimge as NSNumber))
        }`